# Issue creating statcast database with BaseballR Package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a database of all MLB statcast outcomes. For this, I am using the `baseballr` package made by Bill Petti https://billpetti.github.io/2020-05-26-build-statcast-database-rstats-version-2.0/. I am not connecting to a SQL database but simply making a data frame in R. I want to collect all statcast data from 2019 and 2020. First, I loaded in the necessary packages.

```
library(baseballr)
library(tidyverse)
```

Then I executed the `annual_statcast_query` function:

```
annual_statcast_query <- function(season) {
  
  dates <- seq.Date(as.Date(paste0(season, '-03-01')),
                    as.Date(paste0(season, '-12-01')), by = 'week')
  
  date_grid <- tibble(start_date = dates, 
                      end_date = dates + 6)
  
  safe_savant <- safely(scrape_statcast_savant)
  
  payload <- map(.x = seq_along(date_grid$start_date), 
                 ~{message(paste0('\nScraping week of ', date_grid$start_date[.x], '...\n'))
                   
                   payload <- safe_savant(start_date = date_grid$start_date[.x], 
                                          end_date = date_grid$end_date[.x], type = 'pitcher')
                   
                   return(payload)
                 })
  
  payload_df <- map(payload, 'result')
  
  number_rows <- map_df(.x = seq_along(payload_df), 
                        ~{number_rows <- tibble(week = .x, 
                                                number_rows = length(payload_df[[.x]]$game_date))}) %>%
    filter(number_rows > 0) %>%
    pull(week)
  
  payload_df_reduced <- payload_df[number_rows]
  
  combined <- payload_df_reduced %>%
    bind_rows()
  
  return(combined)
  
}
```

When I ran his code for the 2019 season `payload <- annual_statcast_query(2019)`, I could scrape the data without any problems. However, when I tried it for 2020 `payload <- annual_statcast_query(2020)` I encountered the error:

```
Error: Can't combine `spin_rate_deprecated` <logical> and `spin_rate_deprecated` <character>.
```

This error occurs in the last part of the `annual_statcast_query` function:

```
  combined <- payload_df_reduced %>%
    bind_rows()
```

When reading through the statcast documentation (https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/csv-docs), it appears that the variable `spin_rate_depreceated` was replaced by `release_spin`. Perhaps this is why I am encountering this error. I do not need this variable for my analysis, and the error tracing I did made it very obvious that fixing the problem is beyond my skill set as a college student.

```
> rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
Can't combine `spin_rate_deprecated` <logical> and `spin_rate_deprecated` <character>.
Backtrace:
  1. global::annual_statcast_query(2020)
  3. dplyr::bind_rows(.)
  4. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
  6. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
  7. vctrs:::vec_ptype2_df_fallback(x, y, opts)
  8. vctrs:::vec_ptype2_params(...)
  9. vctrs:::vec_ptype2_opts(x, y, opts = opts, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
 11. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
 12. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
 13. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 14. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/vctrs_error_incompatible_type>
Can't combine `spin_rate_deprecated` <logical> and `spin_rate_deprecated` <character>.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-global::annual_statcast_query(2020)
  2. | \-payload_df_reduced %>% bind_rows()
  3. \-dplyr::bind_rows(.)
  4.   \-vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
  5.     \-(function () ...
  6.       \-vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
  7.         \-vctrs:::vec_ptype2_df_fallback(x, y, opts)
  8.           \-vctrs:::vec_ptype2_params(...)
  9.             \-vctrs:::vec_ptype2_opts(x, y, opts = opts, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
 10.               \-(function () ...
 11.                 \-vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
 12.                   \-vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
 13.                     \-vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 14.                       \-vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

Therefore, I tried to drop this variable from my database before the bind rows operation to avoid the error.

```
combined <- payload_df_reduced %>%
    payload_df_reduced[ , !names(payload_df_reduced) %in% c("spin_rate_deprecated")] %>%
    bind_rows()
```

However, this returned the error message:

```
Error in .[payload_df_reduced, , !names(payload_df_reduced) %in% c("spin_rate_deprecated")] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I am running
`packageVersion("baseballr") [1] ‘0.8.3’` 
On R 4.03

If anyone could help me find a way to do this, that would be amazing. I am not picky about how I get this data, so I am all ears if anyone has an idea. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To drop a column from data.frame you should do this:

```
payload_df_reduced %>%
    select(-c(spin_rate_deprecated))
```

or if using your current way it should be like this

```
payload_df_reduced[ , !names(payload_df_reduced) %in% c("spin_rate_deprecated")]
```

Your current code is not work because it is incorrect grammar.

It seem that your payload_df_reduced is a list of data.frame not one data.frame. I tried to run your code but it seem you have other functions so not reproducible. Here is a theory code that you may need to adjust a bit.

```
combined <- map(payload_df_reduced, select, -c(spin_rate_deprecated)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```